# Notification onBackpressed should opens default LAUNCHER activity always

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have implemented gcm Notification's for my android app with `PendingIntent` which will take user to an Activity when notification will be clicked now, I have defined types of notification's switching user to other's activities and when user press back button app closes which I don't want.

I want is to open **LAUNCHER activity** always which is defined in manifest when user click `back button` from an `Activity` open from Notification.  Is there any way to achieve it ? thanks in advance

Comment: you can use a boolean with shared prefrences and handle your scenario or can implement onbackPressed and handle your scenario

Comment: @UsmanKurd thanks, yes you are right i Handle `onbackpress` event in all activities  but i want any other solution if possible to handle this scenario

Comment: handle with shared pref u can use that as well

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Refer this link :
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse
> ```
>
> First define Activity hierarchy in AndroidManifest.xml for Launcher
>   activity.Also build your notification as follows :

```
    <activity
    android:name=".LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".LauncherActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".LauncherActivity"/>
</activity>

        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotif`enter code here`icationManager=
        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());
```